# How to Call Web API in Azure Data Factory Dataflow Sink

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am developing the pipeline which is using dataflow component to read the parquet file from data lake. final result we are getting select activity to get the table result.
I have to call the web API call to pass my dataflow result, the each row, I have to give the as a input parameter to all web API.
I could see web API call option in SINK option but how to read row by row data to call my API.
Kindly provide suggestion or examples.

> Note : as per requirement, we can't use any stage storage or database.

[image]

above the dataflow activity the final JOIN result provided no of rows and columns. I have to read each row and pass the data to my web API or restful call until the row completed.

how do we handle in SINK operation to success the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

For sending the data through REST Api you can use `ForEach`  and `Web` activity in adf.

Follow below steps,

First, sink the data in dataflow as  `Cache` sink type and check the `Write to activity output` option as shown below.

[image]

Next add `ForEach` activity in pipeline. Inside ForEach add
`Web` activity.

```
@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value
```

Then select **ForEach** activity, in settings tab there is option called
**Items** there add above expression accordingly as shown below. Here `sink1` is my sink activity name, add your sink name accordingly.

[image]

Then select Web activity, there add your post request url, select method as **POST**. In body add `@item()` as shown below.

[image]

Then debug the pipeline.

Below is the output by `Dataflow` , only four columns.

```
"output": {
       "sink1": {
           "value": [
{
"density": "0.9978",
"pH": "3.51",
"alcohol": "9.4",
"quality": "5"
},
{
"density": "0.9968",
"pH": "3.2",
"alcohol": "9.8",
"quality": "5"
}, 
{
"density": "0.997",
"pH": "3.26",
"alcohol": "9.8",
"quality": "5"
},
{    "density": "0.998",
"pH": "3.16",
"alcohol": "9.8",
"quality": "6"
},
```

I've used postman mock server and `{Status: "Done !!"}` as response for successful POST request.

Below are the result of post request.

[image]

and in postman

[image]

Here, you can see the POST request is sent for each row.

If you need to modify the body, you modify it in web activity **Body** section.